# How to do custom sorting in GROUP BY in mysql?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I need Roll Number count so I am grouping it by **CollCode** it is fetching data in below format with roll Number count sorted by **CollCode** automatically.

```
Centre   Coll.Code   College   Class    RollNo          Total
101      501         A         BCA-I    10001-10200     200
102      502         B         BCA-I    10201-10400     200
103      503         C         BCA-I    10401-10600     200
104      504         D         BCA-I    10801-11000     200
102      508         H         BCA-I    10601-10800     200
```

But I need data Group By **CollCode** but ***sorted by RollNo*** in below format. Kindly help.

```
Centre   Coll.Code   College   Class    RollNo          Total
101      501         A         BCA-I    10001-10200     200
102      502         B         BCA-I    10201-10400     200
103      503         C         BCA-I    10401-10600     200
102      508         H         BCA-I    10601-10800     200
104      504         D         BCA-I    10801-11000     200
```

Comment: You use an order by statement?

Comment: Can you provide SQL request that you are using?